# Sum two $scopes and update database with it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, backand

I'm trying to add points to my Ionic app database. To do that I'm getting existing points from database and add them to the points that I will input. After I want to update those summed points to my database.With my code the browser is giving me error: "server responded with status 500 critical exception"if you have any idea how please help me solve this problem.

(The `$scope.points` and `$scope.input` datatype is float)
This is my code:

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, PointService) {
$scope.points = [];
$scope.input = {};
$scope.sum = parseFloat($scope.points) + parseFloat($scope.input);


function getAll() {
    PointService.getPoints()
    .then(function (result) {
        $scope.points = result.data.data;
    });
}


$scope.updatePoints = function() {
    PointService.addPoints($scope.sum)
    .then(function(result) {
        $scope.input = {};
        getAll();
    });
}
```

Comment: Code shown for sum doesn't make sense . `parseFloat()` is for strings not objects or arrays. Also doesn't make sense to run sum on  empty values. Not clear what you are trying to do here.

Comment: With this application i am trying to add more points to existing points in application database. $scope.points are points that i am retrieving from database and $scope.input are points that I want to add by inserting in application. After the app will add it I want it to update the database. That is what im trying to do. So I should change the $scope.points array and abject into strings?

Comment: depends what points are and what you want to do with them. Neither is clear

Comment: By points i mean numbers. I want to create a rewarding application so the teacher can add rewarding points to students. So the application need to retrieve the amount of points that student has already from db and add the amount that teacher inserts using application. By far my app substitute the existing amount of points with the one i insert and im trying to make it sum the amount of points.

Comment: that doesn't explain what data type they are...array of numbers, single number, array of objects etc. What exactly needs to be summed?

Comment: Numbers of points: for example student has 60 points in his account (database) and teacher wants to add 20.

Comment: do that in the update function, not when controller first loads

Comment: validate what is sent and adjust if needed. Beyond that check server logs to see what causes server error

Comment: If I do it like this I still get "server status 500 critical exception" : 
any idea? 
      `$scope.updatePoints = function() {
  
      var sum = parseFloat($scope.points) + parseFloat($scope.input);  

      PointService.addPoints(sum)
      .then(function(result) {
       $scope.input = {};
      // Reload our points
      getAll();
       });
       }`

Comment: is `sum` a valid number? What do server error logs tell you?

Comment: this is what server logs gives me Cannot convert type 'double' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,object>'

Answer (score 0):

You state in your question that the type of scope.input is float, but you set it to an empty object using

```
    $scope.input = {};
```

As this error is originating on the server, it is the back end data translation that is having problems attempting to convert your empty object to a null floating point value. I suggest changing {} to 0.0 or some other floating point placeholder.